# Compiler doesn't raise an error on a obsolete property used in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Somehow when I compile this in VS 2008 it doesn't raise an error, is there any way to flag it so it does raise an error?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program[] programs = null;

            var result = programs.Where(p => p.Value.Length == 0);
        }

        [Obsolete("Do not use", true)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code won't run anyhow but it should raise an error on compile time, it does mark it as obsolete if you just do `p.Value` but somehow ignores it when you add the `.Length` or any other property/method

Comment: I thought "Obsolete" was a warning not an error

Comment: @Ian: That's what the "true" part means - error, not warning.

Comment: Report at connect.microsoft.com please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I've just tried compiling your code with the C# 4 compiler, and got this:

```
Test.cs(12,42): error CS0619: 'Program.Value' is obsolete: 'Do not use'
```

I wonder if this was a bug in the C# 3 compiler (shipping with VS2008/.NET 3.5) which was fixed for the C# 4 compiler.

Comment: Hi Jon, I think it might be. Just compiled in vs2008 and no compile error (though resharper spots it)

Comment: I assume the vs2010 compiler also raises an error when you compile it as .net 3.5 project?